# $g_P(\xi,\eta):= \int \frac{|\xi - \eta|}{1+|\xi - \eta|} dP$ and $\delta_P(\xi,\eta)=\int [|\xi-\eta| \wedge 1]dP$ satisfy the triangle inequality.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality, metric-spaces

I want to show that $g_P(\xi,\eta):= \int \frac{|\xi - \eta|}{1+|\xi - \eta|} dP$ and $\delta_P(\xi,\eta)=\int [|\xi-\eta| \wedge 1]dP$ satisfy the triangle inequality.

The solution is given below. However, I cannot see how this proves the inequality because we have $1+|\xi - \eta| \le 1+|\xi - \zeta| + |\zeta - \eta|$. How can we show the triangle inequality?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $|x-y| \leq |x-z| + |z-y|$ one need additionally to use that the function $$f(t) = \frac{t}{1+t}$$
is monotonically increasing for $t \geq 0$. In fact, note that $f(0)=0$ and $f'(t) = (1+t)^{-2} >0$.

The monotonicity yields
$$\frac{|x-y|}{1+|x-y|} =f(|x-y|) \leq f(|x-z| + |z-y|) = \frac{|x-z| + |z-y|}{1+|x-z| + |z-y|}.$$
Now your step shows that
$$\frac{|x-z| + |z-y|}{1+|x-z| + |z-y|} \leq \frac{|x-z| +}{1+|x-z|} + \frac{|z-y|}{1+|z-y|}.$$